# Is there a mismatch between MVVM and the possibility to modify the View's component tree?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

Having read all the StackOverflow entries regarding **Model-View-ViewModel architecture** along with most of the readily available resources on the net I have come to the conclusion that it is the de-facto standard for building **SOLID** Silverlight apps.
I started to plan my next application using this architecture. One of the requirements for the application is to build or change the visual component structure. For example, responding to user interaction I would like to programmatically append an unknown-at-compile-time number of Rectangles and Ellipses to a specific Canvas or Canvases.
I started to twist my mind to apply the MVVM pattern and think where the code responsible for attaching the new components should go. I concluded that it doesn't belong to any of the MVVM layers and therefore it is impossible to apply this architecture in scenarious where you have to manipulate the component tree at runtime.
Is there a way to still use **Model-View-ViewModel** in these kind of scenarious or it is only limited to work with a fixed View component structure?

Comment: If anything, MVVM is actually a SUPERIOR pattern for your project because it allows you to so abstractly represent your Data (Model) in a UI (View) by simply using middle-layer (ViewModel) conversion to View-friendly collections and properties, with data templates to visually structure them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't manipulate the component tree. Instead, manipulate a model that represents the component tree. Then have your view bind to the various collections and properties in that model to produce its visuals.

What follows is a really simplified example. **It just shows the concepts - please don't take it as indicative of how you should factor your code.**

First, my model:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public double Left { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I expose a collection of said shapes (you would use another model to contain this collection). Then I bind to it in my view:

```
<Window x:Name="_root" x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Rectangle}">
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Stroke="Black"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_root}" ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Jep. Binding should be your only friend.

Comment: Thank you Kent. It is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: MVVM is much easier in WPF than Silverlight. For example, DataTemplates in Silverlight do not support the DataType property.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem in your question is confusing requirements of your users (manipulating objects that are represented by rectangles and ellipses (I'm only guessing)) with implementation details (appending `Rectangle`s and `Ellipse`s to `Canvas`es).

Again, the different responsibilities in the MVVM pattern:

#### View

Translate the ViewModel into pixels and translate input events into method calls on the ViewModel.

This would be the actual Silverlight components (`Rectangle`, `Ellipse`, `Canvas`) binding against their `DataContext` and having a few very small event handlers or `Command`s or whatever.

#### Model

Hold data and business logic in a domain-specific way.

This represents the "mathematical" rectangles and ellipses your users are drawing.

#### ViewModel

Refine the Model in a UI-oriented and often use-case specific way.

Here you store the transient information like "currently selected object" that are relevant for a specific view but are not attributes of the underlying Model's concept.

Read my blog for [more on my views on MVVM](http://dasz.at/index.php/2008/11/doing-gui-architecture-the-right-way/).